# IVY resolve to latest.release resolves to wrong artifact

Tags: ivy

I have an ivy xml file contains dependencies declarations, but uses the `rev="latest.release"` settings rather than specifying a hard wired revision.

```
     <dependency org="<organisation name>" name="<module>" rev="latest.release"/>
```

The reason I am using latest.release is that every Sunday our build process runs and generates 'release' artifacts for ALL modules in our project.   These artifacts are named `WKXX-YYYY` so for example, the most recent was `WK05-2017`

The problem is, when I do a resolve IVY is resolving the artifacts to version `WK50-2016` and I do not understand why.  The published `ivy.xml` that resides with the artifact on our central ivy repo seems correct and the info section states the correct status eg release and the publication date is also correct.

eg

**WK50-2016**

```
<info organisation="<org name>" module="<module name>" revision="WK50-2016" status="release" publication="20161218140515"/>
```

**WK05-2017**

```
<info organisation="<org name>" module="<module name>" revision="WK05-2017" status="release" publication="20170205140555"/>
```

As you can see from the above, the publication date is more recent in the WK05-2017 artifact.

I have also included the ivysettings.xml that is also used as part of the IVY configuration.

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chained"/>   
    <resolvers>
        <!-- Remote IVY Repo -->
        <filesystem name="remote" changingPattern=".*-SNAPSHOT.*" changingMatcher="regexp" checkmodified="true">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>           
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

        <!-- Local IVY Repo -->
        <filesystem name="local" changingPattern=".*-SNAPSHOT.*" changingMatcher="regexp" checkmodified="true">
            <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>           
            <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.repo.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>  

        <!-- Use both the local and remote repos -->    
        <chain name="chained" changingPattern=".*-SNAPSHOT.*" changingMatcher="regexp" checkmodified="true">
          <resolver ref="local" />         
          <resolver ref="remote"/>         
        </chain>  

    </resolvers>

    <caches defaultCacheDir="${ivy.cache.dir}" ivyPattern="${ivy.cache.ivy.pattern}" artifactPattern="${ivy.cache.artifact.pattern}"/>

</ivysettings>
```

Just for reference.

```
changingPattern=".*-SNAPSHOT.*" changingMatcher="regexp" checkmodified="true"
```

are used as we also use SNAPSHOT integration artefacts that are built and published when commits are made to trunk.   I found that without these attributes ivy would use the local SNAPSHOT even if the version on the remote repo was more recent.

Thanks in advance.